# Highlighting the text content in PDF with foxit pdf library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, foxit, foxit-reader

Trying to highlight a specific text in PDF content with foxit library. I couldn't a find particular method/name in foxit webpdf.mini library file.

1. Am trying to integrate foxit sdk in my own web application to render 
   a pdf content and there is one particular requirement of highlight a specific text content in PDF ,foxit provides a function called highlightText() available in webpdf.mini js file.

2.Inside this function line called 
**m.getPluginByName(i.FindToolPluginName)**,here i coudnt find the method/name FindToolPluginName anywhere inside the foxit sdk.

Note: In older versions of 
foxit 1.2 we have definition for this particular method.
foxit v2.0 it has some alternate method createService(),
foxit v3.0 am currently using and in this version am facing issues for the method not found.

Can i get some idea or does anyone faced similar kind of issue ?is there any specific foxit forum discuss about this problem.